# JavaScript анимация на всплывающее окно

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, не подскажите как сделать анимацию постепенное появление при нажатии на кнопку всплывающего окна и кнопку закрытия на `id=exit` в самом окне.

```js
function showModalWin() {
  var darkLayer = document.createElement('div'); // слой затемнения
  darkLayer.id = 'shadow'; // id чтобы подхватить стиль
  document.body.appendChild(darkLayer); // включаем затемнение

  var modalWin = document.getElementById('popupWin'); // находим наше "окно"
  modalWin.style.display = 'block'; // "включаем" его

  darkLayer.onclick = function() { // при клике на слой затемнения все исчезнет
    darkLayer.parentNode.removeChild(darkLayer); // удаляем затемнение
    modalWin.style.display = 'none'; // делаем окно невидимым
    return false;
  };
}

showModal.addEventListener("click", showModalWin);
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center; display: none" id="popupWin" class="modalwin">
  <h2>Какая-то форма</h2>
  <form>
    <input value="text">
    <input type="button" value="OK">
  </form>
  <hr>
  <a id="exit" href="#">Выход</a>
</div>

<button id="showModal">Показать окно</button>
```

Comment: используй animate css и все дела. после подключения animate css добавь в classList елемента darkLayer и popUpWin классы animated fadeIn

Comment: Не понял, что именно ты хотел сделать. Есть готовая форма, потом пытаешься сделать какое то затемнение... Ты извини дорогой, но у тебя супер кривой пример...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function modal(e) {
 let modal = document.createElement("div"), block = e.cloneNode(true);

 Object.assign(modal.style, {
  position: "fixed",
  left: "0px",
  top: "0px",
  width: "100%",
  height: "100%",
  backgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.5)"
 });

 Object.assign(block.style, {
  display: "initial",
  opacity: 0,
  position: "absolute",
  left: "50%",
  top: "50%",
  transform: "translate(-50%, calc(-50% + 100px))",
  transition: ".6s opacity, .6s transform"
 });

 modal.appendChild(block);

 document.body.appendChild(modal);

 setTimeout(()=>Object.assign(block.style, {
  opacity: 1,
  transform: "translate(-50%,-50%)"
 }),15);

 modal.addEventListener("click", e => e.target === modal ? document.body.removeChild(modal) : "");
}

showModal.addEventListener("click", ()=>modal(modalBlock));
```

```html
<div id="modalBlock" style="display: none; box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px white; padding: 20px; background-color: white;">
 <h2>Modal</h2>
 <p>Modal random text and more random text</p>
</div>

<button id="showModal">Show modal</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо очень помогли!